# How to regenerate expired Dropbox access token of customer (end user)?

Tags: dropbox-api

We have few customers (end users) for whom we have recently started observing expired Dropbox access token as follows:

> Error DropboxApi::Errors::HttpError : HTTP 401: {"error_summary": "expired_access_token/..", "error": {".tag": "expired_access_token"}}

All these customers have already provided necessary permissions to our app & currently have their Dropbox account connected to our app. But due to above error I'm unable to fetch author or video details associated with customer's Dropbox account.

A sample expired access token:

```
"sl.BGkoetSlQMa7KMP-LmYIsSuVGmfY5QoD7ZGtj0wM_IZiWCD1rXS7j0ylaMYQlmvM7xXQg4WGBIFc-tdu9Q9jfZ09WxXpvSIqYWF_G1sCmDJJ_ELrtvZw27iUrUtmoLsdKcDDdc1v"
```

How can I regenerate such expired access tokens of customers?

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-API-Support-Feedback/How-to-regenerate-expired-Dropbox-access-token-of-customer-end/td-p/594094 ]